# SFTP and Append data of the file to already existing file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am new to unix. My client has a requirement to sftp some data files to a legacy system server. In the legacy server there are the same names files already existing. What we want is that when we sftp file to server, it will append the data of the file in the existing file.
Let's say on legacy server there is a file A.dat with 10 rows. Now I am doing sftp file A.dat with 5 rows. So after sftp, on the legacy server file A.dat should have 15 rows. Also, if the file doesn't exists on the legacy system, then the script should place the file.
Any quick response is highly appreciated. My current sftp script looks like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set timeout -1
spawn sftp user@server
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /destinationpath\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /sourcepath\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put A.dat\n" 
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Comment: You do not want to **overwrite** the existed data on the remote server? if yes why you do not use `rsync` .  Or  you want to add to a file which already exists so you want to **append** on those data?

Comment: No, i don't want to overwrite the data. Let me clarify my requirement. There are 3 servers, server 1 and 2 are sending a same name(A.dat) file to server 3. When server 1 is sending file, by the time file from server 2 already reached server 3. So now server 1 file data should get append to file from the server2. Hope this clarifies my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-a` to `put` or use
`reput`. See [the manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#reput) for your version of sftp. It might not be supported or differ.

If it's just one file I would use ssh directy and append to the file:
 `ssh user@server "cat >> /destinationpath/A.dat" < /sourcepath/A.dat`

Make sure to have to use `>>` as `>` would overwrite your file.

Comment: There are multiple files. So, ssh will not work.

Comment: this will only append the file. What if the file doesn't exists on the external server. Will it place the file also?

Comment: ssh user@server "cat >> /destination/A.dat" < /source/A.dat  works for me. It appended the data when file already exists, and puts the file if it doesn't exist. Could you please help me with writing this in a script as I have to do this for multiple files in a script.